# How to register a user with Email instead of username in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've read tons of stack overflow posts about how to register a user with email instead of username but none of them seem to work, so I'm resetting to my defaults. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605384/how-to-make-django-register-users-with-emails-instead-of-username) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email) but I still get 'username is required' back from the API when I try to register user.

I think the problem might be that I couldn't find a post that's explicit to Django 3 and uses Django Rest Framework.

Below are my models, serializers and views.

```
# models
class User(AbstractUser): 
    ROLES = (
        ('d', 'Doctor'),
        ('s', 'Secretary'),
        ('p', 'Patient'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=ROLES, blank=True, default='p', help_text='Role')

class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clinic = models.ManyToManyField(
        Clinic, related_name="doctors", blank=True)
    appointment_duration = models.IntegerField(default=20, blank=True)

# serializer
User = get_user_model()
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'role', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}

# viewset
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

So, how could I register with email instead of username?

Comment: Set the `username` to the `email` and keep them in sync. In model `User` `def save(self, *args, **kwargs): self.username = self.email; return super().save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Must though tutorial on this : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: @RossRogers this error shows: ```line 23, in save self.username = self.email "AttributeError: 'UserSerializer' object has no attribute 'email'"```

Comment: Not in the `UserSerializer`.  In the `User` model itself.

Comment: It worked! Are you aware of any limitations/problems I might encounter down the line because of doing it this way?

Comment: That's what I've done for years and haven't hit limitations.

Comment: would you like to add it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `username` to the `email` every time you save to keep them in sync. In model `User`:

```
class User(AbstractUser): 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.username = self.email
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `username` field in the Django can be used to store any string with such restrictions:

`150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.`

So it is possible to use username as an email too without any restrictions.
You can override the Auth mechanism of the DRF to validate email in the provided username and validate the password. Check this [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication) for details.

Also, you can find several approaches to extend the Django User model.
Details are in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django) discussion.